# Unity Firebase is not initializing on Android

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have a Firebase Unity project for Android. I'm currently using Unity 2019.3.1 and using Firebase SDK 6.15.2. Below is the code I used to connect to Firebase:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.Firestore;
using Firebase.Extensions;

public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static FirebaseManager instance;
    private FirebaseApp app;

    private async void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = this;
            var dependencyResult = await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();
            if (dependencyResult == DependencyStatus.Available) app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance; 
            else Debug.LogError($"Failed to initialize Firebase with {dependencyResult}");
        }
    else Debug.LogWarning($"An instance of {nameof(FirebaseManager)} already exists!");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("FirebaseManager.Start()");
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => 
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            Debug.Log("var dependencyStatus = task.Result;");
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available) InitializeFirebase();
            else Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
        });
    }
}
```

Firebase works on Unity. However, when I build the apk and tested it out, it did not go to `Debug.Log("var dependencyStatus = task.Result;");`. I tried using many solutions found online such as using a different Unity version or the latest Firebase SDK or re-importing Firebase but none of them work.

Edit: It seems that the `Start()` function ends at `FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread`
and will not go any further than that even if there is a Debug.Log after the function.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some other fix I have missed?

Comment: Did you try force resolving it?    Assets => External Dependency Manager => Android Resolver => Force Resolve            This will simply force the Firebase plugin in Unity to do its work.

Comment: @Disavowed I just tried it but faced the same issue, it doesn't work.

Comment: You're doing check and fix dependencies twice (in start and awake). Is that intended, and does it work if you remove one (ex: the Start)? This could be my own fault of course, and I kind of jump between methods in my tutorial videos .

Comment: Also, any logcat output when it fails would be helpful. You can view it right in Unity (filtered to your game) if you use the logcat extension from the Unity package manager: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html

Comment: @PatrickMartin yup the error was caused by that, i removed one and it now works

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen you should always call the firebase initialization in Awake instead of Start.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).