# Unity Firebase is not initializing on builds

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

This is the exact same problem presented in this question: [Unity Firebase is not initializing on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294408/unity-firebase-is-not-initializing-on-android)
But the solution to that one doesn't work for me because the code is different.
When I run the app in Unity, Firebase is initialized correctly, but when I build the app, for Android or PC, it doesn't initialize.
I write my code from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6du3DUTIPI

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class FirebaseInit : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public UnityEvent OnFirebaseInitialized = new UnityEvent();

    private void Start() 
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Error al inicializar Firebase con {task.Exception}");
                return;
            }

            OnFirebaseInitialized.Invoke();
        });
    }
}
```

I have Unity 2019.4.4f1 and the latest Firebase SDK

Comment: Can you capture your debug output via LogCat? It's hard to say without any logging. If you're new to Android development, I recommend trying this plugin to capture logging: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html

I would recommend moving `SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled` until after you check for `task.Exception`, but it's hard to tell what's going wrong from what's here. Also hi, that's me in the video!

Comment: @PatrickMartin OMG! yeah, I know that's you! I was about to close this question because I finally found out a solution. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, I guess I'll use that for future problems, which I'll probably need because I'll use Cloud Functions next, and I still don't understand well how to use them in Unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but without fixing the actual problem.
I installed the Unity Editor using the offline installation, so it appears that this method doesn't download all the needed Android dependencies, because I tried installing again the Editor, but through the Unity Hub this time and the problem disappeared.